# PWA 'Hello World' keeps giving me a service worker error on Manifest Tab of dev tools - can't install as an app

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have read all I can on service workers and PWA's and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, I think it must be my virtual directory on IIS or something but I have tried changing the scope of the service worker registration, changed the start_url in the manifest, etc., and nothing seems to work.  The error I get is in the dev tools on the Application->Manifest tab:

"Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the current page also controls the start URL from the manifest"

I have created a virgin application on IIS called TestWeb and can browse to a 'hello world' page at 
https://localhost/TestWeb/

All the js files and the manifest are in the root of the site. In the header of the page, I have:

```
 <link rel="manifest" href="Manifest.json">
```

and that points to a json file in the root of the site like so:

```
{
  "dir": "ltr",
  "lang": "en",
  "name": "xxxx",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": ".",
  "short_name": "xxxx",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "description": "",
  "orientation": "any",
  "background_color": "transparent",
  "related_applications": [],
  "prefer_related_applications": false,
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "Images/AppIcons/windows10/Square71x71Logo.scale-400.png",
      "sizes": "284x284"
    },
    etc...
```

For the scope of the manifest, I have tried "./", "/", "/TestWeb/", "/TestWeb", etc..  When the document is ready, I call this function:

```
    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {

        if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
            console.log("Active service worker found, no need to register");
        } else {
            // Register the service worker
            navigator.serviceWorker
                .register("ServiceWorkerRegister.js", {
                    scope: "./"
                })
                .then(function (reg) {
                    console.log("Service worker has been registered for scope: " + reg.scope);

                });
                //.catch(err => console.log(err));

        }
    } 

}
```

For the scope here, I have tried "./", "/", "/TestWeb/", "/TestWeb", etc..

The service worker successfully activates and is running but there is no 'add' button on the browser, and going to the Application->Manfiest in dev tools, I get the error saying no matching serivce worker.  I have tried refreshing multiple times.

I am stumped, does anyone know of something else to try?

Comment: Does your PWA when running with an HTTPS URL pass as a valid PWA with the Chrome Lighthouse tool? This will usually give you some good hints on what to look at if there are problems.

Answer (score 0):

To get installation prompt your source code must have this (ServiceWorkerRegister.js) file with at least an event listener for fetch, and other installable requirements too.

Comment: Yes it does have all those requirements: